# JS variable is displayed as undefined when using HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am working on a project on Google Apps Script. I have a JS function that returns a date (as a text). I also have an HTML document to display a form with several inputs. I would like to prefill one input with the date returned by the JS funtion. It almost works, except it displays "undefined" instead of the date, even though I know the js funtion is working fine.
Here are some code to better understand :

The input where I call the script (don't mind the onmousemove, i just didn"t find anotherway to call the script).

`<input type="text" id="deliveryDate" name="deliveryDate" onmousemove="displayActiveDate()">`

So it calls the folowing script.

```
<script>
    function displayActiveDate(){
      var activeDate = google.script.run.getActiveDate();
      document.getElementById("deliveryDate").value = activeDate;
    }
</script>
```

Which in turn calls getActiveDate() which is the separate JS function that returns the date.

If you have any idea on how to solve this, I will be very thankful.

Comment: I suspect `google.script.run.getActiveDate()` is not in the scope `displayActiveDate()` (probably the entire `google` object is not in the scope).

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run — "google.script.run is an **asynchronous** client-side JavaScript API" So it isn't going to return a value. Read the documentation for it.

Comment: You need to have the `withSuccessHandler()` callback, read the documentation

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, following the documentation on ```withSuccessHandler()``` did in fact work (with a slight delay but I guess there is nothing to do about that since it needs to do the callback). Thanks everyone !

Comment: Great, I will write up a proper answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`google.script.run.serverSideFunction()` returns `undefined`. In order to get the actual response value from your `serverSideFunction()` you need to use the `withSuccessHandler()` method with a callback like so:

```js
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).serverSideFunction();

function onSuccess(data) {
  // do something with the data returned by the serverSideFunction()
}
```

Also note that you also have `withFailureHandler(err)` to handle any errors you  server-side functions may return.

Here is the [full reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Answer (score -2):

Instead of writing `document.getElementById("deliveryDate").value = activeDate;` type `document.getElementById("deliveryDate").innerHTML= activeDate;` in your script

Comment: That won't work. The question is about pre-filling an **input**, so there can't be any child nodes, so `innerHTML` will have no effect.